# Compare for each columns with all other columns from two different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two similar tables in a database.

- First, I want to compare the value for each column in Table A with the value for each column in Table B (1:1 comparison) and calculate the max_overlap_length for each row.
- Second, I need to return a single table containing the average of max_overlap_length for each operation

```
Table A
|    A         |  B      |    C     |
|--------------+---------+----------|
|    123ABC    |   222   |    552   |
|    543BCD    |   333   |    442   |
|    421GGG    |   888   |    882   |
|    123AAA    |   555   |    122   |
|-----------------------------------|

Table B
|    1         |  2      |    3     |
|--------------+---------+----------|
|    ABC125    |   221   |    522   |
|    ABC543    |   331   |    422   |
|    AAA421    |   100   |    822   |
|    AAA123    |   552   |    122   |
|-----------------------------------|

Example: compare Table A (column A) with Table B (column 1): A-1

|    A         |      1     | max_overlap |
|--------------+------------+----------|
|    123ABC    |   ABC125   |    3     |
|    543BCD    |   ABC543   |    2     |
|    421GGG    |   AAA421   |    3     |
|    123AAA    |   AAA123   |    6     |
|    ...       |   ...      |    ...   |
|--------------------------------------|

If we do the operation, we might compare all the columns with the following scenario:
A-1, A-2, A-3, B-1, B-2, B-3, C-1, C-2, C-3

(expected) Final Output:

| Tbl1  | Tbl2  |   avg    |
|-------+-------+----------|
|   A   |   1   |    3     |
|   A   |   2   |    2     |
|   A   |   3   |    3     |
|  ...  |  ...  |   ...    |
```

Here's my attempt (limitation: 1 table = 1 column)

```sql
WITH data AS (
SELECT
      table_a.col, table_b.col,  
    CASE  
        WHEN LENGTH(table_a.col) = 0 OR LENGTH(table_a.col) = 0 THEN 0 
        ELSE ( 
            SELECT MAX(length) 
            FROM ( 
                SELECT LENGTH(SUBSTRING(table_a.col, start, length)) AS length 
                FROM generate_series(1, LENGTH(table_a.col)) AS start 
                CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, LENGTH(table_a.col) - start + 1) AS length 
                WHERE POSITION(SUBSTRING(table_a.col, start, length) IN table_b.col) > 0 
            ) AS subquery 
        ) 
    END AS max_overlap_length 
FROM table_a, table_b 
order by max_overlap_length desc nulls last)
SELECT AVG(max_overlap_length) FROM data;
```

If each table has **n** columns, how to perform the above operation efficiently using the **PostgreSQL**? Currently, the number of tables is limited to 2 tables, and I am still new to PostgreSQL.

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

Comment: PLSQL is used by Oracle databases, not PostgreSQL. I've removed the non-applicable tag.